# LINQ to SQL filter child collection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm strugling with this query, i think I'm missing something.
I have two autogenerated dbml models.

```
    public partial class RegulatorsOrganizationView
    {
        private int regulatorOrgId;
        private string regulatorOrgName;
        private EntitySet<RegulatorsView> regulatorsViews;
    }

    public partial class RegulatorsView
    {
        private int regulatorId;
        private string regulatorName;
    }
```

- I need to apply filtering by name, input string "filterText" should be a part of regulatorName
- If regulator is not matching - should be filtered out from regulatorsViews
- If regulatorOrganizationView have at least one match in regulatorsViews - should be included
- If regulatorsViews collection of regulatorOrganizationView does not have regulators that match condition, but it's name contains filterText - it should be included.

Currently I'm loading all the matching regualatorsOrganizationViews, and do filtering on regulators down the line.

```
List<RegulatorOrganizationView> regOrgs = boatDataContext.RegulatorOrganizationView
                .Where(r => r.RegulatorsViews.Any(ar => ar.regulatorName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper()))
                || r.regulatorName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper())
                .ToList();
```

But this way I'm loading **redundent** **Regulators** only to filter them out later on.
How can I rebuild this query to load only matching regulators from starters ?

It tried to use **Select()** to assign regulatorOrgnization filter list of Regulators.

```
            regulatorsOrgs = DataContext.RegulatorOrganizationViews
            .Where(ro => ro.regulatorOrgName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper())
            || ro.RegulatorsViews.Any(r => r.regulatorName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper()))
            .Select(ro => new RegulatorOrganizationView()
            {
                regulatorId = ro.regulatorId,
                regulatorOrgName = ro.regulatorOrgName,

                RegulatorsViews = ro.RegulatorsViews
                         .Where(r => r.regulatorName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper())
                         .Select(r => new RegulatorsView()
                         {
                             regulatorId = r.regulatorId,
                             regulatorName = r.regulatorName,
                         }).ToEntitySet()
            
            }).ToList();
```

But I'm getting exception: Message=**"The explicit construction of the entity type 'RegulatorsOrganizationView' in a query is not allowed."**

Looks like filtered **Include()** would be an option (like in EF) but I can't find a way to use it with Linq To SQL.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ-to-SQL it's a bit messy and not intuitive to do this. You have to use [DataLoadOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var opt = new DataLoadOptions();

opt.AssociateWith((RegulatorsOrganizationView v) 
    => v.regulatorsViews.Where(ar => ar.regulatorName.Contains(filterText)));

opt.LoadWith((RegulatorsOrganizationView v) => => v.regulatorsViews);

DataContext.LoadOptions = opt;

var result = DataContext.RegulatorOrganizationViews
            .Where(ro => ro.regulatorOrgName.Contains(filterText) 
                      && ro.regulatorsViews.Any());
```

So this says: when loading `RegulatorOrganizationViews`, then *when* their `regulatorsViews` are associated, make them meet the given condition.

Then it says: when when loading `RegulatorOrganizationViews`, also load their `regulatorsViews`.

The latter is like `Include` in Entity Framework. The former makes it behave like filtered `Include`, or maybe closer, a global query filter.

I removed the `ToUpper` calls for brevity, but you don't need them if the database collation is case-insensitive.

Comment: It's indeed as you say - messy and not intuitive. no wonder I strugled. But you solution works good for me, thanks a lot.